# Amplitude for neutron-proton conversion from first principles

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, cosmology

I'm reading Dodelson's *Modern Cosmology*, and in one of the exercises on Big Bang nucleosynthesis it is quoted without reference that the amplitude for neutron-to-proton conversion is given by

$$|\mathcal{M}|^2 _{n+\nu_e \rightarrow  p^ + e^-} = 32G_F ^2(1+3g_A ^2)m_p^2 p_\nu p_e $$
with $g_A$ the axial-vector coupling of the nucleon.

Does anyone know a reference for a derivation of this amplitude from first principles?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You just go to a reputable particle physics text, like Chapter 5.1-5.6 pp 30,31,35,36 of L B Okun's legendary workhorse *Leptons & Quarks*, North Holland, 1982, ISBN-13: 978-0444869241 , and slug through it. Might also do Prob 10.4 for eqn (10.43) and finally eqn (10.44), p 310 of D Griffiths' *Introduction to Elementary Particles*, Wiley 2008, ISBN-13: 978-3527406012.

Further, there are dozens of write-ups like [this](http://aesop.phys.utk.edu/ph611/2012/projects/Hayes.pdf) on the internet, or [else](https://www.physi.uni-heidelberg.de/Publications/ckm_byrne.pdf).

I have not line-reversed the antineutrino of neutron decay to your quasielastic neutrino-neutron scattering, but Okun deals with it on pp143-144 Ch 17.  An early classic by C.H.Llewellyn Smith, [Physics Reports **3** (5), June 1972, pp 261-379](https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-1573(72)90010-5), has all the stuff on pp 301-302, but you'd cloy yourself in a surfeit of form-factors...

Comment: Can you point to some specific equations / page numbers perhaps?

Comment: Okun, pp 30-36, where the local notation is explained in p 34.